# Is having 1million PHP session files in the same folder something I should worry about?

Tags: php, session

Running CentOS and ext4.  How many files in a folder is a problem, and why?  Or is a million plus no bother at all?

Other than reducing the number of sessions I keep hold of, are there other solutions, if it is a problem?

Comment: That many files in a single folder is always going to be slow access, whatever filesystem you're using

Comment: have a look at the timestamps of the files, maybe you can delete 99% because they are old

Comment: I moved from the standard 20 minute sessions to a week when I implemented my own shopping cart (versus paypal's) the other day, which has obviously caused the increase.  I guess I can probably set it so the session is 20 minutes UNLESS the user adds an item to a cart, and then it's valid for a week.

Comment: If it's a shopping cart the solution is not via sessions, you better keep track of baskets separately, like in a DB.

Comment: I keep the basket in the database, and just a guid for the basket in the session.  Is there a better solution?